Issues with Generating SHA-256 Hash Report During USB Drive Scanning in PowerShell Script
I am trying to create an isolated computer for USB drive decontamination using a script that scans my USB drive and generates a report in the directory C:\ScanReports. However, I am encountering an issue with my code. The problem is that it fails to find the directory C:\ScanReports. After analyzing my code line by line to pinpoint the issue, I found that the problem lies here: Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\kenny:' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1

Get-ChildItem -Path "$($Volume.DriveLetter):"

  + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\kenny\::String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand




Write-Host "Surveillance des disques USB..."
Can anyone help me resolve this issue? Thank you!
Write-Host "Surveillance des disques USB..."

function Show-Notification {
    param ([string]$Message, [int]$DisplayTime = 3)
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    $form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $form.Text = "Notification"
    $form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(350, 150)
    $form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
    $form.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::FixedDialog
    $form.TopMost = $true
    $label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $label.Text = $Message
    $label.TextAlign = "MiddleCenter"
    $label.Dock = "Fill"
    $label.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 12, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
    $form.Controls.Add($label)
    $form.Show() | Out-Null
    Start-Sleep -Seconds $DisplayTime
    $form.Close()
    $form.Dispose()
}

function Show-Progress {
    param ([string]$Message)
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    $form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $form.Text = "Analyse en cours"
    $form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(350, 150)
    $form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
    $form.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::FixedDialog
    $form.TopMost = $true
    $label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $label.Text = "$Message, veuillez patienter..."
    $label.TextAlign = "MiddleCenter"
    $label.Dock = "Fill"
    $label.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 12, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
    $form.Controls.Add($label)
    $progressBar = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar
    $progressBar.Dock = "Bottom"
    $progressBar.Style = "Continuous"
    $progressBar.Minimum = 0
    $progressBar.Maximum = 100
    $progressBar.Value = 0
    $form.Controls.Add($progressBar)
    $form.Show() | Out-Null
    return [PSCustomObject]@{Form=$form; ProgressBar=$progressBar}
}

function Update-Progress {
    param ([PSCustomObject]$ProgressDialog, [int]$Value)
    if ($ProgressDialog -and $ProgressDialog.Form.Visible) {
        $ProgressDialog.ProgressBar.Value = $Value
    }
}

function Close-Progress {
    param ([PSCustomObject]$ProgressDialog)
    if ($ProgressDialog -and $ProgressDialog.Form.Visible) {
        $ProgressDialog.Form.Close()
        $ProgressDialog.Form.Dispose()
    }
}

function Get-FileHashSHA256 {
    param ([string]$FilePath)
    $sha256 = [System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256]::Create()
    $stream = [System.IO.File]::OpenRead($FilePath)
    $hash = $sha256.ComputeHash($stream)
    $stream.Close()
    return [BitConverter]::ToString($hash) -replace "-", ""
}

$ReportsPath = "C:\ScanReports"
if (-not (Test-Path -Path $ReportsPath)) { New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $ReportsPath | Out-Null }

while ($true) {
    try {
        $USBDrives = Get-CimInstance win32_diskdrive | Where-Object { $_.InterfaceType -eq 'USB' }
        if ($USBDrives) {
            $Volumes = Get-Volume | Where-Object { $_.DriveType -eq 'Removable' }
            foreach ($Volume in $Volumes) {
                Show-Notification -Message "Lecteur détecté !" -DisplayTime 2

                Start-Sleep -Seconds 5  # Attente pour assurer que le lecteur soit prêt

                $progressDialog = Show-Progress -Message "Analyse en cours"
                $scanJob = $null
                $progressValue = 0
                $VolumeRemoved = $false
                while ($true) {
                    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
                    $VolumePresent = Get-Volume -DriveLetter $Volume.DriveLetter -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
                    if (-not $VolumePresent) {
                        Show-Notification -Message "Lecteur retiré. Annulation." -DisplayTime 2
                        Close-Progress $progressDialog
                        $VolumeRemoved = $true
                        break
                    }

                    if (-not $scanJob -and $VolumePresent) {
                        try {
                            $scanJob = Start-MpScan -ScanPath "$($Volume.DriveLetter):" -AsJob
                        } catch {
                            Show-Notification -Message "Erreur de démarrage de l'analyse. Réessayez." -DisplayTime 3
                            Close-Progress $progressDialog
                            break
                        }
                    }

                    if ($scanJob.State -eq 'Running') {
                        $progressValue += 10  # Augmenter par 10 à chaque mise à jour pour réduire la fréquence
                        $progressValue = [math]::Min($progressValue, 98)
                        Update-Progress -ProgressDialog $progressDialog -Value $progressValue
                    } elseif ($scanJob.State -eq 'Completed') {
                        Update-Progress -ProgressDialog $progressDialog -Value 100
                        Close-Progress $progressDialog
                        break
                    } elseif ($scanJob.State -eq 'Failed' -or -not $scanJob) {
                        Close-Progress $progressDialog
                        Show-Notification -Message "Erreur pendant l'analyse. Réessayez." -DisplayTime 3
                        break
                    }
                }

                if (-not $VolumeRemoved -and $scanJob -and $scanJob.State -eq 'Completed') {
                    $ReportText = @("Date : $(Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')", "Lecteur : $($Volume.DriveLetter):")
                    $ReportText += "Résultat : Aucun problème détecté."

                    $files = Get-ChildItem -Path "$($Volume.DriveLetter):" -Recurse -File
                    foreach ($file in $files) {
                        $hash = Get-FileHashSHA256 -FilePath $file.FullName
                        $ReportText += "Fichier : $($file.FullName)"
                        $ReportText += "SHA-256 : $hash"
                    }

                    if ($VolumePresent) {
                        $ReportFileName = "Rapport_$($Volume.DriveLetter)_$(Get-Date -Format 'yyyyMMdd_HHmmss').txt"
                        $ReportFilePath = Join-Path -Path $ReportsPath -ChildPath $ReportFileName
                        $ReportText | Set-Content -Path $ReportFilePath -Encoding UTF8
                    }

                    $ScanResult = Get-MpThreatDetection | Where-Object { $_.Resources -like "$($Volume.DriveLetter):*" }
                    $message = if ($ScanResult) {
                        $ReportText += "Menaces détectées :"
                        foreach ($Threat in $ScanResult) {
                            $ReportText += "- Nom : $($Threat.ThreatName)"
                            $ReportText += "  Chemin : $($Threat.Resources)"
                        }
                        "Menaces détectées. Rapport généré. Veuillez retirer la clé USB."
                    } else {
                        "Aucune menace détectée. Rapport généré. Veuillez retirer la clé USB."
                    }
                    Show-Notification -Message $message -DisplayTime 5
                    Show-Notification -Message "Analyse terminée. Veuillez retirer la clé USB." -DisplayTime 10

                    # Attendre jusqu'à ce que la clé soit retirée
                    while (Get-Volume -DriveLetter $Volume.DriveLetter -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
                        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
                    }

                    # Notification pour attendre 30 secondes avant de reprendre la détection
                    Show-Notification -Message "Veuillez attendre 30 secondes avant de rebrancher une clé." -DisplayTime 10

                    # Attendre 30 secondes avant de reprendre la détection
                    Start-Sleep -Seconds 30
                }

                while (Get-Volume -DriveLetter $Volume.DriveLetter -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
                    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
                }
            }
        }
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    } catch {
        Write-Host "Erreur dans la surveillance des disques USB : $_"
    }
}



I recently posted a question about an issue I'm facing with a PowerShell script for USB drive decontamination and received a -1 rating. I'd like to clarify the situation and provide more context to help resolve the problem.
I am trying to create an isolated computer setup for USB drive decontamination using a PowerShell script. The script scans my USB drive and generates a report in the directory C:\ScanReports. However, I am encountering an issue where the script fails to recognize the parameter -File.
Here is the error message I am getting

Get-ChildItem : Cannot find a parameter with the name 'File'.
At line:1 char:65

$files = Get-ChildItem -Path "$($Volume.DriveLetter):" -Recurse -File

                                                            ~~~~~


CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument : (:) [Get-ChildItem], ParameterBindingException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Get-ChildItemCommand




Looks like you are using an ancient version of PowerShell, because the -File switch on Get-ChildItem was already present in version 3.0. If that is the case, I would urge you to upgrade to at least version 5.1. Otherwise use $files = Get-ChildItem -Path "$($Volume.DriveLetter):\" -Recurse | Where-Object { !$_.PsIsContainer }. The error in the post itself is because you don't test if a volume actually has a Driveletter. (some drives may not have that. When  $Volume.DriveLetter results in $null, the system resolves the path to your current file path in $PWD

I'm actually on powershell 5.1, I understand better now thank you very much
